# Awaiting multiple HTTP Requests

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Scenario : Sending a `POST` to 2 different endpoints (not related to or dependent on each other).

I'm really just not sure if I went about this correctly, and whether or not the responses will have returned from the context before the method returns. I have read some about async/await and the context for which it operates, etc., but I'm still not sure.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await SendRequests(cookie, request1, request2);
            })
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();

        }

static async Task<List<HttpResponseMessage>> SendRequests(Cookie cookie, HttpRequestMessage punchRequest, HttpRequestMessage request2)
        {
            List<HttpResponseMessage> responseMessages = new List<HttpResponseMessage>();

            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
            cookies.Add(cookie);

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                var response1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request1);
                var response2 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request2);

                responseMessages.AddRange(new [] { response1 , response2 });

                return responseMessages;
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm wondering if :

1. `Task.Run( async () => ....)` is correct here, as well as `GetAwaiter/GetResult`
2. Can the `SendRequests` method ever return before the requests finish / get resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Task.Run(async () =>
> {
>     await SendRequests(cookie, request1, request2);
> })
> ```

is a very long-winded way of writing

```
SendRequests(cookie, request1, request2)
```

---

`.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is also a long-winded way of writing `.Result`, but since you're ignoring the return value it's probably necessary.

---

> Can the `SendRequests` method ever return before the requests finish / get resolved?

Of course. Otherwise it would return `List<HttpResponseMessage>` rather than `Task<List<HttpResponseMessage>>`. However, assuming that wasn't the question you actually intended to ask...

The [doc for `SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh138176.aspx) says

> The returned task object will complete once the entire response including content is read.

Since you `await` both of the tasks, the responses must finish before the `SendRequests` task will finish. (Of course, if the first one throws an exception then the second won't even be sent).

It's not clear to me whether the intention was for the requests to be made in parallel. That seems to be implied by

> to 2 different endpoints (not related to or dependent on each other).

In that case you would want to create the tasks and then wait for them both:

```
var responseTask1 = httpClient.SendAsync(request1);
var responseTask2 = httpClient.SendAsync(request2);
await Task.WhenAll(responseTask1, responseTask2);

responseMessages.AddRange(new [] { responseTask1.Result, responseTask2.Result });

return responseMessages;
```

Although I have to say that I don't understand the purpose of creating `responseMessages` in the outer scope.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing it and for the information. I think I leaned toward trying to use `async / await` because of the `SendAsync` method, but what you're saying is that there's really no benefit with async here at all?

Comment: @Mark, I'm not saying that. If you're getting it from the last section of my answer, the point there is that I wasn't sure whether you thought you were getting some parallelism, and I wanted to explain a) that you aren't; b) how to get it if you want it.

Comment: Be advised, that `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` encapsulates the occurring Exception in an `AggregateException`, while `Task.Run()` doesn't. :-)